# Как в imagemagick отмасштабировать изображение с промежутками между пикселями?

Tags: imagemagick

Есть маленький спрайт:

```
# спрайт Марио в base64 записать в файл:
magick 'inline:data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAO
xAGVKw4bAAAA00lEQVQ4ja1UwRGDMAyTe7zLJmWUzMoodBO6gHmkhsRWcukVvYID
kiKbiKoqbsTjTjIAmLq7IvXzwGHahJ5sUKBJKKhf3rcVAPB8pZ5BTihyEcxLomuD
Fxhqyryk06WtDZ93LSB+bMqYvBtPBsQYA2FP3YPl2XUIAIpcsCZ5eRM18slvALyL
CoFAu5EApCn7tsbx+hY0U55llmkYG7NefuhzKAVFUv1Mm8L+EgKWa5zDQbIWqiNn
riuvID8g1r4c2Hi6Ghvg6sg/mqEIDv+9v2+/sQ8vtmAvY/Wf0QAAAABJRU5ErkJg
gg==' mario.png
```

Я хочу отмасштабировать его в 8 раз:

```
convert -scale 800%  -quality 100 mario.xpm mario-big.png
```

Но отмасштабировать нужно с отступами между пикселями. Чтобы между четырьмя соседними увеличенными в 8х раз пикселями был отступ в 1 пиксель. Либо наложить поверх сетку цвета фона с учётом размеров исхоного спрайта.

Как можно это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста?

Пример того, что я хочу увидеть:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эту задачу можно решить с помощью следующей команды:

```bash
convert mario.png \
  -scale 800% \
  -crop 0x8 -splice 0x1 -append \
  -crop 8x0 -splice 1x0 +append \
  -chop 1x1 output.png
```

Если исходное изображение было 20x20 пикселей, то на выходе получим изображение размером 179x179:

[image: output.png]

Разберем по шагам:

- [`-scale`](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#scale) — масштабирование изображения, увеличиваем изображение в 8 раз с помощью команды `-scale 800%`.
- [`-crop`](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) — эта команда нарезает изображение на куски указанного размера. Если передаем `0` в качестве ширины, то берется максимальная ширина. То есть `-crop 0x8` нарежет изображение на горизонтальные полоски размера 160x8.
- [`-splice`](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#splice) — добавление строк или колонок в указанное место. Команда `-splice 0x1` добавит полоску размера 160x1 в начало изображения. Эта команда применяется к каждому куску из предыдущего шага.
- [`-append`](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append) — этой командой соединяем модифицированные изображения с предыдущего шага в одно изображение. Изображения соединяются друг за другом по вертикали.
- Далее аналогично применяются `-crop` и `-splice`, но изображение нарезается по вертикальным полоскам.
- [`+append`](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append) — соединяет изображения в горизонтальном направлении.
- [`-chop`](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#chop) — операция, противоположная splice, удаляет указанные строки и столбцы. Команда `-chop 1x1` удалит столбец и строку по 1 пикселю в начале изображения.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень круто. Лучше другого варианта, где пришлось резать кучу файлов и добавлять цикл.. А можете объяснить, что происходит в вашем скрипте? Хочется понимать.

Comment: Подробнее изучил процесс, большое спасибо за разложение по полочкам и разметку markdown.  С чужих объяснений понять, пусть и не сразу, могу, но сам сгенерировать, сколько не читал инструкций по IM - не могу. Неужели я тупой?)  
Зачем в данном случае ``-chop 1x1 `` попробовал без него - получается тоже самое, только без смещения. Запутался, как лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Мне ещё так советовали с циклом:

```
magick mario-big.png -crop x8 mario-row-%02d.png ; for f in mario-row-*png ; \
do echo $f; magick "$f" -crop 8x -background "#fffffe" +smush 1 "$f"; done ; \
magick mario-row-*png -background "#fffffe" -smush 1 mario-big3.png ; rm mario-row-*.png
```

Это же подробнее bash-скриптом:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Chop into rows, each row being 50px tall
magick artistic-swirl.jpg -crop x50 row-%02d.png

# Iterate over rows, chopping each into 50px wide chunks and recombining with 1px spacing
for f in row-*png ; do
 echo $f
   magick "$f" -crop 50x -background yellow +smush 1 "$f"
done

# Smush the new rows together vertically with 1px spacing
magick row-*png -background cyan -smush 1 result.png
```

Почти то, что надо, только временные файлы создаёт и их потом удалять надо. И нельзя указать для рамки оба цвета как white - продают все цвета вообще. Обхожу это указывая на байт меньше: #fffffe Глазу разницы не видно, но почему так, кто скажет?

Подробности тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73590651/i-want-to-scale-the-sprite-8x-with-padding-between-pixels

Comment: Старайтесь давать чуть более развернутые ответы и пояснять что происходит в приложенном вами коде, чтобы пользователи, которые столкнулись с той же проблемой смогли понять, что вы делаете, почему и как вы к этому пришли... в противном случае пользы от него для окружающих не так много

Comment: ОК. просто не успел добавить описание.

Comment: плюсик вам в карму

Comment: `Обхожу это указывая на байт меньше: #fffffe Глазу разницы не видно, но почему так, кто скажет?` вопросы в ответе писать - тоже не лучшая идея :)

Comment: Следует ли из-за такой мелочи создавать новый вопрос?

Comment: если хотите получить ответ - то да. Искать вопросы в ответах тут точно никто не будет. И отвечать ответом на ответ тоже. И даже если вы это перенесете в тело текущего вопроса - скорее всего этого никто не заметит, потому что вопрос уже решен и имеет два ответа. То, что ответ изменился после получения этих ответов и что он требует каких-то новых ответов никто предполагать не будет. Более того правилами сервиса установлено, что посты в которых содержится более одного вопроса  стоит разделять. Так что все зависит от того насколько вы хотите получить ответ.

Comment: Это просто совет, а не руководство к действию. Я просто объясняю как сервис работает и предупреждаю что на вопрос заданный в ответе вы ответа не дождетесь - далее уже решать вам.